# How To Add Value To Specified Column In DataTable with SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Several days ago, I just known about SqlCommandBuilder Class. So, Now i try to do **CRUD Operation** with `SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataTable)` Method

I had tried this :

```
I Have Table Named "Student" with 3 Columns, "idstudent","Name","Class"

//Assume We Have Open SqlConnection
//conn = SqlConnection Variabel
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", conn);
SqlDataAdater da = new SqlDataAdater(cmd);
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

//Then, I try to insert with SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataTable) Method
dt.Rows.Add('1','AnyName','2');
da.Update(dt);
```

Finally, My question is how to insert data like below :

```
dt.Rows.Add
(
    'idstudent' => '2',
    'Name' => 'Ruka',
    'Class' => '3'
);
//Then Finally Update
da.Update(dt);
```

*What i want to do is like **Laravel** `Create()` parameters. We say what column we wanted to insert value*

I had read about lambda expression but it's not help me to do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["idstudent"] = 2;
row["Name"] = "Ruka";
row["Class"] = 3;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add rows by doing this

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"blah", "blah2", "blah3"});
```